# Как правильно работать сW3C validator?

Tags: html-validation

Поступила задача исправлять ошибки найденные с помощью сервиса  [validator.w3.org](https://%20validator.w3.org) После введения url, иногда остаюсь на validator.w3.org, а иногда перекидывает на [validator.w3.org/nu/](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) , Можно и сразу проверять сайт на validator.w3.org/nu/. Почему так происходит? Где надо проверять сайт? Ошибки выдаёт абсолютно разные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Nu Html Checker (v.Nu) is an ongoing experiment in better HTML checking..." .... экперимент по улучшенной проверке HTML. Поэтому, проверяйте validator.w3.org - это официальное, не ночная сборка)